# Where to place the add and remove buttons for a list box?

Tags: lists, windows-os

In a Windows Form, where should the Add / Remove buttons go when you have a header record with single attribute children, as below? Should the "Child Items" label be above the list box?

[image: Screenshot]

**Update:**

Trying to apply DripDrop's suggestion:

[image: Screenshot Updated]

Comment: In an optimum situation, there probably shouldn't be a separate dialog for adding an entity in the first place, so the question is moot.

Comment: In an optimum situation you would not be using WinForms.  Remove should not even be enabled if an item is not selected.

Comment: @Jawa it's just an input box. Could have been a textbox on the main form, I just found it easier.

Comment: @Blam WinForms is what we're using in my company right now. What would you use, WPF?

Comment: This is a more of a developer talking but WPF is a league up.  I can not only do more with less code but with the controls and how they layout deliver a better UX.  In WPF everything is a content control so you can put an image or text in a button.  You have styles to modify presentation and keep things consistent.  WPF has a higher resolution and more colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine, and I would!dent move it. What I would suggest is that you group the list and the buttons together, so the user immediately knows that they are together.

EDIT: Yes, that looks great.

Comment: Please see my update with a new screen shot. Is that what you had in mind? A group box? I think it looks better...